# Qual a melhor maneira de armazenar um item multivalorado

Tags: mysql

Ao emitir uma [NF-e](https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/principal.aspx) é possível inserir [até 990 produtos/itens por documento](http://www.oobj.com.br/bc/article/qual-a-quantidade-m%C3%A1xima-de-produtos-que-podem-ser-informados-em-uma-nfc-e-473.html) . Sendo que cada produto, possui vários atributos. Qual seria a melhor forma de armazenar e vincular cada produto, e seus respectivos atributos, à uma NF-e?

Atualmente possuo a seguinte estrutura:

Tabela `nfe`:

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_nfe` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_emitente` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
...
```

Tabela  `tributos_prod`:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_nfe` int(11) NOT NULL,
`codigo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
...,
KEY `fk_nfe` (`id_nfe`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_nfe` FOREIGN KEY (`id_nfe`) REFERENCES `nfe` (`id`)
```

**Problema**: como cada produto/item irá possuir um ID exclusivo, ocorreria o crescimento "infinito" da tabela `tributos_prod`, impossibilitando um controle manutenível, pois ao **Autorizar** a emissão de uma NF-e posso remover todos produtos vinculados a esta, ou até mesmo pela simples ação de remover um único item.

Answer (score 1):

na tabela de itens, faça uma chave composta, sendo:

```
nfe (pk=id) (unique= numero, serie, modelo, emitente)
id | numero | serie | modelo | emitente | data_emissao | chave | destinatario | ...



nfe_itens (pk=item,nfe_id) (fk=nf_id)
item | nf_id | produto | valor | quantidade | ...
```

onde o `item` da nfe_itens é sequencial mas não `AUTO_INCREMENT` dessa forma, cada nfe inicia a sequencia novamente, item 1, item 2, item 3... por ai vai

Há situações de se utilizar a mesma tabela para registro de um Atendimento, ou Guia de um plano de saúde por exemplo, nesses casos, recomendaria uma chave composta de 3 colunas, pois os itens podem variar entre produtos / serviços / medicamentos / entre outros, então esse `tipo` seria a 3ª coluna na chave primária composta da tabela.